# Replacing a large percentage of rows in a mySQL table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, temp-tables

I'm aggregating data from one table into another using a query similar to these:

```
DELETE FROM wp_popular WHERE popular_type='favorites';
INSERT INTO wp_popular (post_id, popular_type, period, popular_value) 
  SELECT post_id, 'favorites' AS popular_type, '30-days' AS period, COUNT(user_id) AS popular_value ;
  FROM wp_favorites WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= favorited_date 
  GROUP BY post_id;
INSERT INTO wp_popular (post_id, popular_type, period, popular_value) 
  SELECT post_id, 'favorites' AS popular_type, '' AS period, COUNT(user_id) AS popular_value 
  FROM wp_favorites GROUP BY post_id;
```

This is locking the table for almost a minute. No good.

My first thought was to do the work in temporary table and then dump the contents into the original table. This looks something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wp_new_popular LIKE wp_popular;
INSERT ...
DELETE FROM wp_popular WHERE popular_type='favorites';
INSERT INTO wp_popular SELECT * FROM wp_new_popular;
```

Those last two queries are still taking a couple seconds each. Any suggestions how I can speed that up?

I can restructure my app a bit so that the contents of `wp_popular` are completely wiped out and replaced. I supposed I could then `TRUNCATE` the table and replace it's contents. Would it be quicker to just delete `wp_popular` and rename `wp_new_popular` in its place? Can I do that with a temporary table?

Comment: the above 1st block query will commit an error at line no 3 because of semicolon.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you copy data into a de-normalized table? Does putting the right index and querying from the main table directly not work for you?

Comment: Renaming a temporary table to a real table seems to work, but the table still disappears when the connection is closed. That looks like a dead end.

Comment: @Tomalek I haven't tested, but I'm basically amortizing the cost of finding, for example, the top 10 most favorited posts in the last X days by caching this in the wp_popular table. If this query is executed a number of times, which it will be, I would think the de-normalized version would perform better overall. It isn't a requirement for the top 10 to be current. Thanks for making me think hard about whether this is necessary!

Comment: Maybe you should try that first. With a proper index these things should go pretty fast. Have one index over `(favorited_date, post_id, user_id)` and try how fast your first SELECT is with that.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the suggestion. I found another index that I could add which squeezed out a bit more performance, but de-normalization was still necessary.

Comment: Then that's the way it is, I guess. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to create a new (normal) table, do all my expensive operations with it, and then swap it with the existing table using `RENAME`. It looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_new_popular LIKE wp_popular;
INSERT ...
RENAME TABLE wp_popular TO wp_old_popular, wp_new_popular TO wp_popular
DROP TABLE wp_old_popular
```